# Choosing which instance method to use

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring, instance-methods

I wrote some code which takes a bunch of objects, uses an instance method on each of them and puts the value returned from the instance method in a list.

```
object_list # list of objects
value_list = [object.method() for obj in object_list]
```

I need this structure in a lot of different places in my code, the only difference between them being the instance method `method` is always a different one.

It would be no problem to use a [mapping approach as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426261/how-can-the-program-choose-between-two-function-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top) if the methods would be functions. Something similar could be done with `exec`, however it's not very elegant, and I'm unsure about how it would work regarding the returning of the values:

```
def call_method(obj, method_name: str):
    return exec("obj." + method_name + "()")  # returns None
```

Is there an elegant way to refactor the code for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From best to worst, these options work:

```
getattr(obj, method_name)()
operator.methodcaller(method_name)(obj)  # needs import operator
eval("obj." + method_name + "()")
```

The second version can also be used like this:

```
value_list = list(map(operator.methodcaller(method_name), object_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def call_method(obj, method_name: str):
    return getattr(obj, method_name)()
```

The `getattr` function get the attribute and return the function, the last pair of signifies function call.